CTS testing error, APK wont be installed (Aapt parser is failing)
Actually i'm working on a cts module testing in a user-binary device through my linux machine.
module i'm trying to run: CtsHealthConnectControllerTestCases
command i'm using in cts-tradefed: run cts --module CtsHealthConnectControllerTestCases
error i'm getting:
Total tests : 1
Passes : 0
Failed : 0
Important: Some modules failed to run to completion, tests counts may be inaccurate
Early failure resulting in no testRunStart. Results might be inconsistent:
com.android.tradefed.targetprep.TargetSetupError[AAPT_PARSER_FAILED | 520050 : DEPENDENCY_ISSUE] : AaptParser filed for file CtsHealthConnectControllerTestCases.apk, The APK wont be installed.
I have signed in to the google account in my device also internet it turned on.
